# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 - Error on Publisher Login

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, transport, publisher, api-manager

I've made a fresh install of WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 on a google cloud VM. I can login fine into my carbon console and access the publisher root.

When I try to login into my publisher console (https://{my_ip}:9443/publisher) I get the following error `Error! Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI`.

Comment: Are you able to login to the Store - https://{my_ip}:9443/store. Can you provide the full stacktrace by editing the question

Comment: Can you replace "localhost" with google cloud VM's public ip address from the  <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml and see.

Comment: Weird thing is that, after i disabled again CSRFPreventionConfig, it worked. I guess I need to chose better the pattern to apply, the default ones aren`t enough.

Comment: @CiroVivacqua : Can you please clearly state the solution, so that, it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Since I'm doing a pillot project, I disabled CSRFPreventionConfig and it worked. Of course, in production mode I'll have to go deeper and change the default pattern accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Had to disable CSRFPreventionConfig, too. Someone should open a ticket in WSO2 Jira.

To disable CSRFPreventionConfig, open `carbon.xml` (`<wso2am-home>/repository/conf`) and set the boolean value of the `Enabled` tag to `false`:

```
<CSRFPreventionConfig>
        <CSRFPreventionFilter>
            <!-- Set below to true to enable the CSRFPreventionFilter -->
            <Enabled>false</Enabled>
            <!-- Url Pattern to skip application of CSRF protection-->
            <SkipUrlPattern>(.*)(/images|/css|/js|/docs)(.*)</SkipUrlPattern>
        </CSRFPreventionFilter>
</CSRFPreventionConfig>
```